# Zookeeper and curator, getting a NoNode exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the error I'm getting (`NoNode`):

```
15172 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1523d43b964001c type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0x57 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/event_spout Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /event_spout
```

Here's the code that causes it:

```
_curator.create()
        .creatingParentsIfNeeded()
        .withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT)
        .withACL(ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
        .forPath(path, bytes);
```

So I'm getting a `NoNode` exception when trying to create a ZNode in the root directory. The [Zookeeper docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html) say:

> If the parent node does not exist in the ZooKeeper, a KeeperException
>   with error code KeeperException.NoNode will be thrown.

But this can't be the  case because the parent node of `/event_spout` is just `/`, and `/` has to exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just did a quick test with this code (substituting path with "/event_spout") and it worked for me. Can you post a complete example of the failure?